# Cannot connect to kafka hosted in cloud from spring boot application

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka

The kafka virual machine address in the Google cloud platform is `xx.xx.xxx.xxx`.

From my local spring boot app that usually connects to the localhost:9092 of the local machine's kafka server, I changed it to the GCP's virtual machine's ip as `xx.xx.xxx.xxx:9092`

But the server start up spits out the warning

```
2020-04-05 15:30:41.356  WARN 7968 --- [| adminclient-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-4] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

and eventually times out. Should there be a different way to connect to cloud kafka from springboot application?

Comment: `DNS resolution failed for a.b.c.d` clearly means your advertised listeners cannot be reached from the place you ran that command. Did you open the GCE network ports for Kafka??

Comment: @cricket_007 I did not open GCE network ports for kafka. How should I do that?

Comment: Maybe read this ? https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following properties are added

`advertised.host.name` in server.properties to public IP address,
`metadata.broker.list` in producer.properties to public IP address,
`host.name` to 0.0.0.0.

These property files will be inside config folder. A restart is necessary.

And it solved the problem. For broker/bootstrap.sever, the public IP address is used in the application after adding the above mentioned properties.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your broker on the GCP VM with a correct `advertised.listener` so that your client receives a correct hostname/IP from it after the initial successful connection.

You can validate the connection and broker metadata provided by the `advertised.listeners` setting using `kafkacat -L`

```
$ kafkacat -b xx.xx.xxx.xxx:9092 -L
Metadata for all topics (from broker -1: xx.xx.xxx.xxx:9092/bootstrap):
1 brokers:
  broker 0 at a.b.c.d:9092
```

The `a.b.c.d.` returned should be an IP or hostname that your client can successfully resolve to the broker itself (not a loopback address, internal network IP, etc).

To understand more see https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: Thanks Robin for the quick response. I get kafkacat command not found error when I tried to execute the command in the GCP virtual machine. Do I have to configure anything to get this working?

Comment: Robin, I was able to kafkacat the a.b.c.d you mentioned. But, still I get the following error.
Removing server a.b.c.d:9092 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for a.b.c.d

Comment: install kafkacat on the same machine as where your Spring code is running. paste the output as an update to your question.